# Why defects reduce electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, material-science, dielectric

I am running a simulation with drift-diffusion equation, Poisson equation and Fourier heat equation with a metal/insulator/metal structure. In my simulation, initially electric field is at the top of the asperity and defect generation is high at that point. Note that the initial field enhancement is higher (50%) for sharp asperity but breakdown voltage reduces about 3%. This seems that defect generation moderates/reduces initial electric field. Could any one explain this this behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

in a sentence: defect equals *inefficiency* and therefore **loss** of **energy**
,to explain: nothing is perfect unless you are talking theoretical, in computers if it calculates without fractions, limitation modifiers that stop it from calculating a certain decimal limit can mess with your calculations. though any way of calculation brings the loss of efficiency in **converting** from any kind to any other kind of energy. humans are centuries away from 100% efficient conversion techniques. and by the way: i mean loss as 'not the energy you're looking for' to clarify.